# Javascript later callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have a class like this in app.js

```
function Player(elem, options){
    this.events = [];  // Queue of events                      
    new Plugin(elem, options, this);    
}

Player.prototype = {
        init : function(){

        },            
        on : function(event,callback) {
            this.events.push(event.toLowerCase(), callback);
        },
        fire : function(){

        }
    };

function Plugin(elem, options, Player){
  // How can i execute in this class the event event-play like
  Player.events[1].apply(this,args.slice(1)); // here is the problem
}
```

I have a class like this in index.html i have this

```
api = new Player("video",{});

api.on('event-play',function(event,data){
        console.log(event);
    });
```

I am instatiating the Player class, and register the event 'event-play' and attach a callback, but inside the Plugin class i cannot execute the event because the index 1 not exists. ( Player.events[1] ) but i am attaching in the on method. 
How can i do that?

Comment: Well, you are calling `Plugin` when the instance is created. At which point the callback doesn't exist yet. You don't explain what the purpose of the code is, so I can't really provide a suggestion for a solution.

Comment: The purpose is trigger the event 'event-play' inside the Plugin class.

Comment: Here is the example in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tnz3031d/

Comment: But *when* do you want to trigger the event? Right now you are triggering it when you call `Plugin`.

Comment: Yes, i want to trigger the event when an call Plugin constructor.

Comment: But no event handler exists at that moment, so what's the point of that?

Comment: The purpose of all that is that i want to trigger an event after new Plugin instantiation.

Comment: Right. At that moment no event handler exists yet. Do you somehow want to "remember" which events have been triggered and retroactively execute the event handlers for past events?